# Generic way to test for initial in go

Tags: go

Is there a generic way to test a variable for initial in Go?

Given these test:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type FooStruct struct {
    A string
    B int
}

type BarStruct struct {
    A string
    B int
    C map[int]string
}

func main() {
    // string isinital test
    var s string
    fmt.Println(s == "")

    // int isinital test
    var i int
    fmt.Println(i == 0)

    // primitive struct isinital test
    var fp FooStruct
    fmt.Println(fp == FooStruct{})

    // complex struct isinital test
    // fail -> invalid operation: fc == BarStruct literal (struct containing map[int]string cannot be compared)
    var fc BarStruct
    fmt.Println(fc == BarStruct{})

    // map isinital test
    var m map[string]int
    fmt.Println(len(m) == 0)

    // map isinital test 
    // fail -> invalid operation: m == map[string]int literal (map can only be compared to nil)
    fmt.Println(m == map[string]int{})
}
```

A: What is the proper way to test `BarStruct` for initial?

B: Is there a generic way to test any var for is initial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reflect.DeepEqual`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual):

```
bs := BarStruct{}
fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(bs, BarStruct{}))
// Output:
//   true
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/v11bkKUhXQ.

**EDIT:** you can also define an `isZero` helper function like this:

```
func isZero(v interface{}) bool {
    zv := reflect.Zero(reflect.TypeOf(v)).Interface()
    return reflect.DeepEqual(v, zv)
}
```

This should work with any type:

```
fmt.Println(isZero(0))
fmt.Println(isZero(""))
fmt.Println(isZero(bs))
fmt.Println(isZero(map[int]int(nil)))
```